# What's mean identifying $V^{**}$ with $V $ under natural map $\tau$

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand what's mean the sentence "identifying $V^{**}$ with $V$ under the natural map" the theorem is:

> Let, $M$ any subset of $V$. If $\dim (V) < \infty$ then identifying $V^{**}$ with $V$ under the natural map, we have 
>   $$M^{00}= \mbox{span} (M)$$
>   In particular, if $S$ is a subspace of $V$, then $S^{00}=S$.

Notes:

i) $M^{00}$ means annihilator of $M$.

ii) The natural map, is a function $\tau : V \to V^{**}$, which sends a vector $v$ to a linear functional $\overline{v}:V^* \to \mathbb{F}$ with $\overline v(f)=f(v)$

Comment: Things are "identified" when we decide to think of them interchangeably. Every vector corresponds to a particular dual dual vector and vice-versa.

Comment: The part about natural means that it is not necessary to specify a basis of either $V$ or its dual space, or double dual space, to display the identification mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally speaking, $\mathrm{span}(M)$ is in $V$ and $M^{00}$ is in $V^{**}$.  So they cannot be equal.  But that "identifying" clause means that we use $\tau$ to show what corresponds in $V$ with what in $V^{**}$.  So a more literal way of saying it would be
$$
M^{00} = \tau\big[\mathrm{span}(M)\big]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is really $(M^0)^0$, and $M^{0}\subseteq V^*$ and $M^{00}=(M^0)^0\subseteq (V^{*})^*=V^{**}$. So the point is that if we use the isomorphism $\tau$ between $V$ and $V^{**}$, we are characterizing the image of $M^{00}$ under this isomorphism.